# Print the contents of threads in FreeBSD

Tags: process, kernel, freebsd

Is there a way we can print the contents of a thread like "threadID", "backtrace" and other "thread plist" in FreeBSD OS.
Something like,
struct thread *td; And this has some contents
print("%d, %s , %P", td->td_tid, td->backtrace, td->td_plist );

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ptrace maybe?